# yocto linux Beaglebone black no gpio directory

Tags: linux, yocto, gpio, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I built a poky build based on yocto kirkstone and the version I have it running is `Linux beaglebone-yocto 5.15.54-rt48-yocto-standard #1 PREEMPT Thu Jul 14 18:52:26 UTC 2022 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

Also, while building I have a custom layer with a bbappend layer which patches the kernel with a PREEMPT RT patch and adds the following to the kernel configs

```
CONFIG_USB_ETH=y
CONFIG_USB_G_NCM=m
CONFIG_USB_MASS_STORAGE=y

CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_GPIO_AGGREGATOR=y
CONFIG_GPIO_VIRTIO=y
```

As you can see I've enabled GPIO_SYSFS, but when I try to access GPIO pins via `/sys/class/gpio` there is not gpio directory in `/sys/class`.

Not sure what is wrong and this is my first time using yocto linux, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "CONFIG_EXPERT=y"

Like this:

```
CONFIG_EXPERT=y
CONFIG_GPIO_SYSFS=y
```